# Notistack - withRouter and withSnackbar - How?

Tags: reactjs, notistack

How do I combine the withSnackbar with withRouter?

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
loggedIn: state.loginReducer.loggedIn
};
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DbPaper));

THIS DOES NOT WORK
export default withRouter(withSnackbar(DbPaper), connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DbPaper));

any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

compose from redux allowed me to add multiple items.
import { compose } from "redux";

export default compose(
withRouter,
withSnackbar,
connect(mapStateToProps, null)
)(DbPaper);